# GD library installed but not working on ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, gd

I've installed GD and run the following: `php -i | grep -i gd` which returns:

```
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/gd.ini,
gd
GD Support => enabled
GD Version => 2.0
gd.jpeg_ignore_warning => 0 => 0
```

I run PHP5-fpm with nginx, without the use of apache2.

I have also run `sudo /etc/init.d/php5-fpm restart` after checking that gd is enabled.

So it's enabled but when I try to do anything with GD it just won't do anything. Any ideas? Thanks.

**phpinfo**
    gd

```
GD Support  enabled
GD Version  2.0
FreeType Support    enabled
FreeType Linkage    with freetype
FreeType Version    2.4.8
T1Lib Support   enabled
GIF Read Support    enabled
GIF Create Support  enabled
JPEG Support    enabled
libJPEG Version unknown
PNG Support enabled
libPNG Version  1.2.46
WBMP Support    enabled

Directive   Local Value Master Value
gd.jpeg_ignore_warning  0   0
```

**Additional .ini files parsed**

```
/etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/gd.ini
```

Comment: That command shows you the "cli" configuration. You can see if GD is enabled for PHP under Apache by calling `phpinfo()` inside a php file, and opening it with your browser.

Comment: It's enabled, I'll update the question with the `phpinfo` data

Comment: @DT.DTDG What are you trying to do with gd? Also do you have gd-libgd installed? (The actual lib, not the php extension)

Comment: @echochamber I'm trying to overlay text on an image to output an image which will go to print. Unsure if gd-libgd is installed, will try install now.

Comment: @echochamber `sudo apt-get install libgd2-xpm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libgd2-xpm is already the newest version.
libgd2-xpm set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 157 not upgraded.`

Comment: @DT.DTDG how did you install the phpgd extension?

Comment: @echochamber `apt-get install php5-gd`

Comment: @DT.DTDG Does lib gd exist at /usr/lib64/libgd.so.*** (or possibly in /usr/lib or /usr/lib32). You can also try `ldconfig -p | grep libgd` to see where its located, but it should be at the previously mentioned location. (*** are version numbers)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58460/discussion-between-dt-dtdg-and-echochamber).

Comment: Still no luck. Anyone else have any ideas? Thanks